# How to prevent unauthorized users from accessing an image on my server just by URL?

Tags: php, http, mobile, webserver, drm

I have a few dynamically generated images on my server (of high business value), which are supposed to be viewed only via our mobile app. The image is simply loaded from the URL as PNG. How can I prevent people from accessing the same image just by using the URL (if they find it out)?

I could use a PHP script which requires a token to serve the image (rather than access it directly). But If someone goes and reverse engineers the mobile app, token can also be found. I could try and hide it really well, but isn't there any other, better solution?

Comment: Someone disassembling your app had to buy it and eventually REGISTER?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can easily rev engineer apk file for Android for example.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that user, downloading the app, already has access to those images. You can use an unique app ID to create (server side) a JWT token. If, instead, to have the app is not enough to see those images and they have to subscribe...even better, same JWT token generated when registering

Comment: Thanks for mentioning JWT token. I don't know it, but I will research it now and see if suitable. One thing is that users don't need to register, so that might be a problem.

Comment: *... prevent __unauthorized users__ ...* - the point is *unauthorized users*. Reverse engineering does not matter if you have authorization by users instead hard-coded authorization for the app. Once you know it is the correct user it does not matter if the image is accessed by app or otherwise. Thus, if you want to prevent unauthorized users you must have some kind of authorization per user built into your system.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I think that wouldn't really solve the problem. Even if the token is generated server side, it still has to be used from the app. That means: the client has to send you the token, and if you're out to reverse engineer the app, it's trivial to get hold of the token, which can be then used by multiple clients, until you invalidate it (this includes simple curl and wget commands). Also, even if this was not the case, you can get the UUID of the app and simulate a call to get a token.

Comment: If you have both the token AND the app then you paid for it and you already have access to those images. Of course it's not 100% secure (it's true for any licensing scheme) but server might be able to minimize these risks...exactly the same way any pay per use application does

Comment: I need to mention that the app is free to download. I just don't want my competitors (other (web)apps) to piggyback on my work.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The problem here is not forbidding access to the images entirely, but preventing others that did not download the app to get them. If there are 100 people interested, you only need one app to get the token, then give it to others who will not need the app to get them, but a simple curl / wget.

Comment: @PrimožKralj I understand your concern, but if someone's determined to get the data, to the point that they'll reverse engineer the app, then no, there is nothing you can do. Including the fact that they're images, people can take screenshots from their phone and redistribute those.

Comment: @ChatterOne yes and no. **Yes**, if data is static and an user can simply take a picture of them then there is little to nothing we can do.
**No**, if data is not static and those images are generated according to user identity: in this case client and server use mutual certificates and the token (with expiration) is generated per session. If you own the app and you want to disassemble it then...it's for your personal use (because you access the same data you have in the app itself) or giving away the cert + the id you're giving away your own _identity_ (and it's the same as case 1)

Comment: More or less it's like an unblocked SIM card: you can switch it between phones but it will always be the same one. Without a secure storage it's hard to mitigate this problem but it's also not that useful.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti No, that's not what I meant. If you accept web requests, there is no way to make it so that they're only accepted by the app. It doesn't matter how convoluted the process for getting the token is. You cannot distinguish if the request is coming from a fake client with the same headers, or from the app. The request will be the same, and that's what the original question was about. The server wants my ID to give me a token? Sure, I'll do the request using curl and the same headers as the app. How do you recognize that? (Because you can see how your id is generated in the app)

Comment: Do you only care about the most current image? How soon after the image is dynamically generated do you stop caring if it's viewed outside the app? As with all DRM questions, there is no 100% effective technical solution.

Comment: @ChatterOne yes, of course you can't recognize the app but you can recognize the user. As you said, nothing stops the user to take a screenshot of the app screen. What you CAN do (if data aren't static, of course) is to tie those images to the user because, in this way, those data makes sense ONLY to that specific user. In short: that HTTP request MUST NOT be _stateless_. Imagine I give you the URL to get the prospect for my investments...it's useless to you because it's _mine_ and it makes no sense to give you the ability to change my own data before requesting the image.

Comment: And, BTW, if you setup a client certificate you do not only make cracker's life slightly harder but you can determined by whom a service has been abused (and you can **revoke** that certificate).

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with that images the same as it should be for restricted content. There are two major points:

1. Protect access to the content (the images)
2. Protect content against brute force not to allow user guess about image path.

The both points could be covered with proxy request through php script.
The first point can be solved with authentication and protection content with a token and ACL (access control level). Make sure the images out of webserver visibility not to access image directly. It could be helpful to rename image after upload and save original name and new name in DB. In this case you can call it from app by original name and access it by new unique real name.

Answer (score 1):

An answer for the question title: just require a login and password and check the user's authorization before sending the image.

An answer for the question body/comments: as mentioned by ChatterOne in the comments, as long as there is a free access to the app, there is no way to prevent the download by a determined person.

Basically, selling/providing the raw data is not the way to go. Selling a service is. As long as you are keeping your app as is, it will leak the data sooner or later. As long as you are constantly evolving, offering more analytics based on the data, more services, more customer satisfaction - data leeches will be always left behind.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas.

1. Everything has to be SSL TLS v1.2+
2. Having a login/password would be best
3. Having succeed in logging the user gets a code  **random 64 bytes or more**
4. The request is modified so instead of https://www.etc.com/file you have https://www.etc.com/**random 64 bytes or more**/file
5. The code expires either when the user logs out or time based
6. Time base is more secure, and the app can fetch a new code every say 5 minutes
7. Each code is internal tied to an IP address, and the user has to re-login if it changes.
8. Any IP submitting false 64 bit token is banned. say 20 minutes.

If they MITM the SSL cert and packet dumped the traffic it might still be possible, but the bar is raised significantly.  Certificate signing and pinning make this incredible difficult.

This way no fixed code is stored in the app.  The user has to pass through a user/password check to even get said code.  Even if you publish the source code a valid user name and password will still not be present.

Each user and if multiple logins per user are allowed each instance has a different key.  If they have a cell phone and a tablet.

Without a username/password any process can be reverse engineered.  The 64 bit token can't be easily guessed, but the process of getting one could eventually be guessed.

PHP has a "session id", and you could symlink the session id to the real folder internally.  Deleting said folder after 5 minutes or etc.  Probably better to use a secure random function.

Comment: PHP allows passing raw file contents to the output. Instead of moving the image to example.com/[random path]/image.png, you can just have example.com/image.png, and configure the web server to invoke /image.php which can check authentication, such as session IDs or other tokens in other cookies negotiated between the app and server...  [continued]

Comment: The image to serve would be kept outside of the document root in all cases...  or even saved in a database in a blob field.  The only thing you'd get if you're guessing paths is an endless stream of 404 responses.